# JavaScript event delegation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just thought I could use event delegation on ul element so that a click on any of the li elements will bubble up to ul. This is then captures by ul's event.target to get the right li element and proceed according to what I need with the li. This is the way I learnt. But clicking on the contact li element is not alerting as expected. Please help me with this. My company forces me to use event delegation. That's why this is so important.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul id="nav">
            <li id="click"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var list = document.getElementById("nav");
list.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
switch(event.target.id) {
case "click":
alert("haha");
break;
}, false);
```

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li a {
line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
}
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
    background-color: #071726;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus {
    background-color: #326773;
}
```

Comment: could anyone fiddle the answer?

Comment: and what do you see in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: I dont see the alert.

Comment: unexpected token. why is this happening?

Comment: @user2899508: *"unexpected token. why is this happening?"* Because of the issue I mention in the first paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that there's a syntax error in your event handler, you're missing the `}` for the `switch`. (Using consistent indentation will help avoid those kinds of errors.)

Then your problem is that `event.target` isn't what you think it is. `event.target` is the actual element that was clicked. The odds in your case are that the actual element that was clicked is the `a` element (the link).

So what you want to do is look at the lineage from the clicked element down to the element on which you hooked the click (which will be `this`), looking for the one that's at the level you want (in your case, an `li`): [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/UCUnOZO/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/UCUnOZO/1/edit)

```
var list = document.getElementById("nav");
list.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Start with the element that was clicked
    var li = event.target;

    // You may want `event.preventDefault();` here

    // If the element exists, it isn't the list on which we hooked
    // the event, and its tag name isn't LI, go to the parent
    // element instead.
    while (li && li !== this && li.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "LI") {
        li = li.parentNode;
    }

    // If we got an LI, use it
    if (li) {
        // OR you may want `event.preventDefault();` here
        switch(li.id) {
            case "click":
                alert("haha");
                // OR you may want `event.preventDefault();` here
                break;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Also, be sure that the code above is either in a `script` element **below** your navigation list in the HTML, or in an `onload` handler (I recommend the former, just put the script at the end).

And finally: Since the link's `href` is just `"#"`, I'm guessing you don't actually want the link to be followed by the browser (as that will scroll up to the top of the page). If that's the case, you'll want to add a call to `event.preventDefault()` in the handler. I've noted a few places above where you may want it, it depends on whether you *always* want to prevent the link from being followed, or only in certain cases.

---

Side note: Although you can, of course, do this work yourself, you can reuse the work of others by using a good library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). For example, in jQuery, that looks like this:

```
$("#nav").on("click", "li", function(event) {
    // Possibly with `event.preventDefault();` here
    switch (this.id) {
        case "click":
            alert("haha");
            // OR possibly with `event.preventDefault();` here
            break;
    }
});
```

Other libraries have similar features.

Comment: could u please fiddle the same, coz ur code is not giving me the alert either, T.J. Crowder.:-(

Comment: @user2899508: Maybe **you** could create a fiddle showing that it isn't working.

Comment: @user2899508 how hard it is to copy paste.. here's a fiddle of this answer http://jsfiddle.net/EXmrQ/  and it's working..

Comment: but not on chrome browser. please help me. why is chrome not displaying the alert here?

Comment: @user2899508: It works on Chrome (that's where I tested it), and will work on any other major browser. If it's not working for you, there's some *other* problem with the code you're testing.

Comment: is it because i have an <a> element on the html and an overriding on the JavaScript?

Comment: i mean the JavaScript overriding of href=# didn't work, I think.

Comment: @user2899508: See the note above about `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: am i supposed to preventDefault the particular li element? Okay, that sounds good to me.

Comment: @user2899508: No, you call `preventDefault` on the *event*. It's the *event* that you're preventing the default action of.